# mysqldump for particular ID and date range

Tags: mysql, backup

```sql
mysqldump -uroot -p --no-create-info --no-create-db hawa_new scada_data wind_turbine  "SELECT  s.* FROM scada_data as s,wind_turbine as w WHERE s.local_tm BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND s.turbine = w.id AND w.pooling_station = 29" |gzip > /var/lib/mysql-files/sd_feb.sql.gz
```

In which I got the ERROR

```
Couldn't find table: "SELECT  s.* FROM scada_data as s,wind_turbine as w WHERE s.local_tm BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND s.turbine = w.id AND w.pooling_station = 29"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches you could take here depending on whether you want a dump of INSERT statements or are happy dumping data to a CSV format to use elsewhere with LOAD DATA INFILE. Both versions assume you want to use gzip and have access to the command line.

**mysqldump method**

You can get use the mysqldump --where clause to filter for records that match values in a second table but you'd need to make a few changes to what you have now

Change your --where clause to remove the SELECT and FROM parts and match on wind_turbine records in a sub-select

Add a switch to ensure that you get a consistent dump from the database (either --lock-all-tables or --single-transaction).

Remove the table `wind_turbine` from the list of tables because it will not match the --where clause and you only want to dump the data in `scada_data`.

Something like this should work:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --single-transaction --no-create-info --no-create-db  --where "local_tm BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND turbine IN (SELECT id FROM wind_turbine WHERE pooling_station = 29" hawa_new scada_data | gzip > /var/lib/mysql-files/sd_feb.sql.gz
```

**SELECT INTO OUTFILE method**

(which is identical to your original query and probably the way I'd do this myself)

```
mysql -e "SELECT s.* INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/sd_feb.sql' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM scada_data as s,wind_turbine as w WHERE s.local_tm BETWEEN '2018-02-01' AND '2018-02-28' AND s.turbine = w.id AND w.pooling_station = 29"; gzip /var/lib/mysql-files/sd_feb.sql
```